Setting the Background Color of a Gluon RichTextArea
Gluon have added a RichTextArea class:
Gluon's RichTextArea 
Does anyone know how you set the background colour? By default it is white but I'd like it to be the same light grey as other JavaFX dialogs/windows.

What have you tried? The style sheet for RichTextArea is just a couple of clicks from the link in your question. Which properties did you try to modify? What happened when you tried it?

Thanks for your reply. I tried setStyle("fx-background-color: red") on an RichTextArea object but it didn't do anything. I'm not familiar with this css, and assume I try and set the colour of one of the ".rich-text-area .paragraph-tile" styles ??

Gave up with RichTextArea and resorted to using the stock JavaFX TextFlow and setting the font properties on each Text child. Far easier.

I took advantage of what creators of component put in their samples of usages at github repo of RichTextArea
.rich-text-area > .paragraph-list-view {
   -fx-background-color: red;
}

highlightDemo.css
